# Creating functions from following code in python

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to create functions from the following code but am having trouble. I've posted the code i want to make functions out of up top and my failed attempt at the bottom. Thanks for your help

```
inputFile = open(inputPath)
name = ""
for line in inputFile:
lineSegment = line.split(", ")
if name != lineSegment[0]:

    if len(pointList) > 0:
        # Create new polyline object and insert it into featureclass
        polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
        cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
        print "Added " + name
varialbe temporarily
    name = lineSegment[0]

    pointList = arcpy.Array()


    point = arcpy.Point(lineSegment[1], lineSegment[2])
    pointList.add(point)
else:

    point = arcpy.Point(lineSegment[1], lineSegment[2])
    pointList.add(point)

polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
print "Added " + name
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
inputFile = open(inputPath)
pointList = arcpy.Array()
name = ""
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
lineSegment = line.split(", ")
name = lineSegment[0]
point = arcpy.Point(lineSegment[1], lineSegment[2])
lines = ""

def createlines(inputfile):
newlines = ""
for line in inputFile:
    lineSegment = line.split(", ")
    if name != lineSegment[0]:
        if len(pointList) > 0:
            cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
            pointList.add(point)
        else:
            pointList.add(point)
            return newlines

def polyline():
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(pointList)
cursor.insertRow((name, polyline))
return polyline
```

Comment: What's your question? Do you get the wrong output (if so, what output)? Do you get an error (if so, which error)? Something else?

Comment: So how is that failed whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/206073/115